# R RODBC sprintf not working

Tags: r, printf, rodbc

I am familiar with SAS but new to R. I am trying to pull data from a Netezza datamart and have no issue to get the data by typing in the date. But when I try to use sprintf with a dynamic date, the error message shows below. Thanks for reading my post and any help from you is appreciated, thank you!

my code works when typing the date:

```
test<- sqlQuery(db,"
SELECT DISTINCT
B.ACCOUNT_NB,
A.CUSTOMER_NBR,
C.DATA_AS_OF_DT as MONTH_END_ENTRY_DT_LR,
C.REGION
FROM  xxxxxxx
WHERE xxxx
AND C.DATA_AS_OF_DT= '2017-11-30'
)
```

Same code DON'T work when using sprintf:

```
dt='2017-11-30'
test<- sqlQuery(db,sprintf("
SELECT DISTINCT
B.ACCOUNT_NB,
A.CUSTOMER_NBR,
C.DATA_AS_OF_DT as MONTH_END_ENTRY_DT_LR,
C.REGION
FROM  xxxxxxx
WHERE xxxx
AND C.DATA_AS_OF_DT= %s",dt)
)
```

error msg is

> test
>   [1] "HY000 46 ERROR:  Inconsistent datatypes 'DATE' and 'INT4'"
>   [2] "[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect '\n                    SELECT DISTINCT\n  ............................      AND J.DATA_AS_OF_DT= 2017-11-30\n                         \n                         \n                         '"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should enclose the SQL string into quotation marks (`'%s'`) within the string used in `sprintf`:

```
dt='2017-11-30'
test<- sqlQuery(db,sprintf("
SELECT DISTINCT
B.ACCOUNT_NB,
A.CUSTOMER_NBR,
C.DATA_AS_OF_DT as MONTH_END_ENTRY_DT_LR,
C.REGION
FROM  xxxxxxx
WHERE xxxx
AND C.DATA_AS_OF_DT='%s'",dt)
)
```

Otherwise, string `'2017-11-30'` is interpreted as a mathematical expression `2017-11-30` which after subtractions yields `1976`.

Comment: Mark the answer as the one which solved the question, if it solved the question.